# Running glob() from an included script returns empty array

Tags: php, include, wordpress, glob

Perhaps I'm over-looking some minor error somewhere, however I have spent 20 minutes staring at this and re-reading the PHP manual, which is far too long for me to spend on a single line of code.

I am writing a WordPress plugin which is implemented as a class. In my plugin I have the following line:

```
$choices = glob(dirname(__FILE__)."/images/*.{gif,jpg,jpeg,png}", GLOB_BRACE);
```

Clearly I want `$choices` to be an array containing every image in the "images" folder, relative to the included file. The line originally looked like this:

```
$choices = glob("images/*.{gif,jpg,jpeg,png}", GLOB_BRACE);
```

However it was returning an array with several images from an entirely different folder (the `wp-admin/images` folder, to be specific). My best bet is that it's because the function which calls `glob()` was itself called by the `admin_init` hook, which is called by a script in the `wp-admin` folder. In order to make the search relative to my plugin and not the `wp-admin` folder I applied the `dirname(__FILE__)` at the beginning.

My issue now is that I'm getting an empty array. I even tried:

```
var_dump(dirname(__FILE__)."/images/*.{gif,jpg,jpeg,png}");
```

to see exactly what was getting passed. The following was returned:

> string(79) "/home/coupon/public_html/wp-content/plugins/DE-menu/images/*.{gif,jpg,jpeg,png}"

Which looks just fine to me... As I said, perhaps I'm over-looking something simple. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: are images in there? ;-)

Comment: I was about to say "of course", but then I decided it was better to actually check first. Not sure why but Subversion hasn't been uploading any of the sub-directories of my plugin (didn't upload my CSS styles, either). I must have misconfigured something in Subverison. Thank you.

Comment: har har let me write an answer that you can accept :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please add the images to your folder!