# glob() function only returns empty array in php

Tags: php, glob

I've been trying to make a simple website that lets you specify a directory, and embeds a player for each mp3 in whatever directory the user specifies. The problem is that no matter how I enter the directory name, glob() does not return any files. I've tried this with local folders, server directories, and the same folder as the php file.

'directoryPath' is the name of the text box where the user enters, you guessed it, the directory path. The 'echo $files' statement displays nothing onscreen. The 'echo "test"' statement DOES run, but the 'echo "hello"' statement in the loop does not execute.

Any help is appreciated!

```
if (!empty($_POST['directoryPath']))
{
    $path = ($_POST['directoryPath']);
    $files = glob("$path/{*.mp3}", GLOB_BRACE);
    echo $files[0];
    echo "test";
    foreach($files as $i)
        {
            echo "hello";
            echo $files[$i];
            ?>
                <embed src=<?php $files[$i]; ?> width=256 height=32 autostart=false repeat=false loop=false></embed><?php echo $files[$i] ?></p>
            <?php;
        }
    unset($i);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the web server has access to the directory you are trying to glob?  Check your Apache logs for permission error messages.

Also, remove the `;` after `<?php;`

Comment: is your $path holding correct path...? glob() returns  an empty array if no file matched..

Answer (score 0):

Validate the input first:

```
$path = realpath($_POST['directoryPath']);
if (!is_dir($path)) {
    throw new Exception('Invalid path.');
}
...
```

Additionally check the return value [`glob`](http://php.net/glob) returns `false` on error. Check for that condition (and ensure you are not using one of those systems that even return `false` when there are no files found).

I hope this is helpful. And yes, check your error log and enable error logging. This is how you can see what is going wrong.

Also see the following related function for a usage-example and syntax of `GLOB_BRACE`:

- [Running glob() from an included script returns empty array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6883554/running-glob-from-an-included-script-returns-empty-array)

Answer (score 0):

One one tool I find very useful in helping debug variables in PHP is [var_dump()](http://php.net/var-dump). It's a function that provides you with information about a variable's type, it's contents, and any useful metadata it can attain from that variable. This would be a very useful tool for you here, because you'll quickly realize what you have in the variable `$i` is not at all what you expect.

```
$files = glob("$path/{*.mp3}", GLOB_BRACE);
foreach ($files as $i) {
    var_dump($i);
}
/* Here's a hint, $i is not an index to the $files array.
   So $files[$i] makes no sense. $i is actually the value not the key.*/
foreach ($files as $key => $value) { // very different from
    // $key is the key to the current element of $files we're iterating over
    // $value is the value of the current element we're iterating over
}
```

So in your code `$i` is the value not the key. See http://php.net/foreach for more information on how the construct works.

Also, what should be noted here is that you are using a relative path, whereas glob will return an absolute path. By relative this means your searching relative to the CWD (*Current Working Directory*) of your PHP script. To see wha that is you can use the following code.

```
var_dump(real_path('.'));
// similarly ...
var_dump(getcwd());
```